# Monotonic bounded sequence has a unique limit point

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

By **Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorm** we know that every bounded sequence has a limit point. 
I wanted to understand how a **monotonic bounded sequence has a unique limit point**?

Thanks a lot!

**PS:** I am familiar with the following proofs

1. Montonic bounded sequences are convergent
2. Convergent sequence has a unique limit point.

Using these two I can say that Monotonic bounded sequences have a unique limit point. However, I am looking for a simpler and more direct process through which I could directly show the required result

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a non-decreasing monotonic sequence then you can write its limit as the *supremum* of its elements:
$$ \lim _{n\to \infty} x_n = \sup _{n\in \mathbb{N}} x_n$$

It's a well known fact that the supremum of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is unique.

If the sequence is non-increasing monotonic then you just have to take the infinum.

(note that the result can be generalized in other spaces, for example for sequences with values in a totally ordered set)